# MySQL connection error without message

Tags: php, mysql

Following code gives no error message, there is absolute no output. I have tried to run query in phpmyadmin, it is working perfectly.

```
<?php
         $db = mysql_connect(178.62.64.68, user1254, XXXX) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         mysql_select_db(db001) or die('Could not select database');

        $query = "SELECT ID, DATE, SCORE FROM table001 ORDER by SCORE asc LIMIT 10";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

       $result_array = array();  
       while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
           $result_array[] = array(
              'id' => $row['ID'],
              'score' => $row['SCORE'],
              'date' => $row['DATE']
           );
        }        
       echo json_encode($result_array);
?>
```

Comment: What is your error reporting level? Try to run your code with `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: You are missing the quote around your values. They will be treated as constant otherwise.

Comment: You need to pass strings into `mysql_connect()`. Your IP, user, and pass are not wrapped in quotes.

Comment: anything in error_log? i would say query is ok but does not return any rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the quotes around your arguments passed to the functions. The first two lines must be as so:

```
 $db = mysql_connect('178.62.64.68', 'user1254', 'XXXX') or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); // note the quotes (could have been "")
 mysql_select_db('db001') or die('Could not select database'); // note the quotes (could have been "")
```

`string` will be treated as a [`CONSTANT`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php).

`'string'` (or `"string"`) will be evaluated as a [`string`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) (which is what we want here).

Finally, stop using `mysql_*` functions, [they are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Start using [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.